# Connecting API with Joomla 3 using PHP

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I have mobile unlock code remote api which allows user to search for mobile unlock code using dropdown, so I want to attach it to my existing Joomla website. It uses curl to address the remote server so I have no idea how to add it to Joomla so that I can make a dropdown device selection and show unlock codes through remote server API.

I am totally beginner in this so I want to know how to attach it, as it is a php file with json parsing. I will provide any relevant information about my API and Joomla website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add PHP code to Joomla in several ways.

#### [Inside articles](http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/sourcerer)

Using [Sourcerer from NoNumber](http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/sourcerer), you can add PHP code directly inside your content editor (Tinymce). This works inside any article, or inside a Custom HTML module (if you enable "Prepare content" from the **Advanced** tab in your module). Simply wrap your PHP code inside `{sourcerer}{/sourcerer}`.

```
{source}
<?php
    echo 'This text is placed through <strong>PHP</strong>!';
?>
{/source}
```

#### [Flexi Custom Code module](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/flexi-custom-code)

[This module](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/flexi-custom-code) allows you to add any code (Javascript, HTML, PHP etc), and publish it to any module position. Simply paste your PHP code inside the module, set module position and menu item assignment, and save. You can also load the module inside an article using `{loadposition yourmouduleposition}`.

#### Custom Plugin or Module

Another option is to build your own module or plugin. It's not as hard as it might sound, and the possibilities are endless. Here's a couple of resources to get you started:

- [Plugin development tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Plugin_Development)
- [Module development tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Introduction)
- [Plugin generator](http://extstore.com/tools/plugin-creator) (create an empty plugin to get you started)
- [Module generator](http://joomjunk.co.uk/extras-page/module-generator.html) (create an empty module to get you started)

(The module generator is created by [@Lodder](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/168/lodder))

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i am using your above solutions. I hope it works . @johanpw

Comment: @RjRana if this solution works, please mark this answer as question-resolving with the big green tick